# Four squares increasing in size in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to produce a graphical representation of a set of four squares in python. The size of the squares need to be 20, 40, 60, 80 and need to be displayed as they are in the image I have provided. I have also provided some of the code I have already tried which isn't too far off but not correct.

I have tried playing around with some different code but I am really struggling.

Could anyone provide an insight on where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: Following Miguel's answer I have worked out the correct code for what I need to produce. However, I am required to begin at the bottom left of each square. Whereas, my code starts from the top left. Any ideas on where it is wrong?

[image: Required result]

```
from turtle import *
n = 4
for shape in range(1, n+1):
for sides in range(1,5):
    forward(shape*20)
    right(90)

penup()
forward(10+shape*20) # move the pen forward 
right(90) # rotate down
forward(10+shape*20) # move forward now in downwards direction
left(90)
pendown()
```

Comment: do not post pictures of code. post the code itself

Comment: you need to put the final 3 lines inside the for cycle.

Comment: I am new to programming and this website. It wouldn't let me post the code in text as it is saying it is not formatted correctly

Comment: Perhaps you could try again now that you have posted something.

Comment: When you paste code as text into your post, select all of it and press Ctrl-k to format it, then it will let you post.

Comment: you can post the images, but the code should be copy pasted and formated

Answer (score 0):

You should do the movement between drawing the squares, not at the end. Also need to move diagonally to produce an image similar to what you wanted.

```
from turtle import *
n = 4
for shape in range(1, n+1):
    for sides in range(1,5):
        forward(30 + shape*10)
        right(90)

    penup()
    forward(40+ shape * 10) # move the pen forward 
    right(90) # rotate down
    forward(40 + shape * 10) # move forward now in downwards direction
    left(90)
    pendown()
```

Comment: Thank you, that's working for the alignment etc. Just need to play with the numbers to get them correct. The material I have to learn from is very vague

Comment: @Woody89 If you feel like it helped you can upvote/ select as correct in the top left of the answers.

Comment: It's not far off. The square sizes need to be 20, 40, 60 & 80 with them being aligned with 10 units gap horizontally and vertically

Answer (score 0):

> I am required to begin at the bottom left of each square.
>   Whereas, my code starts from the top left. Any ideas on where it is
>   wrong?

Just a matter of a couple of adjustments:

```
from turtle import *

number_shapes = 4

for shape in range(1, number_shapes + 1):

    distance = shape * 20

    for sides in range(4):
        forward(distance)
        left(90)

    penup()
    forward(distance + 10)  # move the pen forward
    right(90) # rotate down
    forward(distance + 30)  # move forward now in downwards direction
    left(90)
    pendown()

hideturtle()

mainloop()
```

We draw the square counterclockwise, instead of clockwise, and increase the amount we move down each time.